# Hudson and Heartbeat causing VPS pain :(

Tags: hudson, heartbeat

I am running a 3 node VPS on vps.net and am having a few weird CPU / Memory usage issues. The box is running the debian binary of Hudson CI, HAProxy and Heartbeat. Over the last week I have been getting various high loads, resulting in the VPS shutting itself down.

When I looked at the monitoring for the server the first time it claimed Hudson was responsible, so I turned it off an let the box run for a day or so until again it failed. This time monitoring claims heartbeat was to blame.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Due to the shared hosting environment sometimes VPSs suffer from  I/O wait and this causes ridiculously high load values.
Monitor the system load with a tool like monit or cacti or whatever you like and see what is causing the high load. Pay special attention to the wait values.